# Editor to assist with navigating through an angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently use Visual Studio as my development environment and would like to be able to navigate through my angular code in a better way.

For example, being able to ctrl-click on an ng-controller to automatically take me to the defined controller would be great - something like 'go to definition' as you can do in C#.  I'm not against using another editor if necessary.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as far as I can tell, the best support we have in the market is code-completion for the ng-attributes.

John Lindquist had mentioned sometime back that support for ctrl-clicking would come eventually, But I guess it will be some time before it does. Until then, this is the best we have.

If you dont have similiar support in Visual studio, I would suggest you to try out the Intellij IDE's with the [angularjs plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=6971).